# Webservice Parsing in Afnetworking

Tags: ios

this is my first webservice parsing.I am not getting JSON result with my code, but I am passing valid JSON where I have checked in JSON lint. Please check my code.

```
-(void)WebParsing{

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    AFJSONRequestSerializer *serializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

    [serializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [serializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [serializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

    manager.requestSerializer = serializer;

    [manager POST:PostUrl parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

    }];
}
```

MY ERROR:

```
 Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: not found (404)" UserInfo={com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7ffeb350f7d0>{ URL:PostUrl} { status code: 404, headers {
        "Cache-Control" = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
        Connection = "Keep-Alive";
        "Content-Length" = 41;
        "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        Date = "Sat, 19 Dec 2015 06:44:34 GMT";
        Expires = "Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT";
        "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=100";
        Pragma = "no-cache";
        Server = "Apache/2.4.16 (Amazon) PHP/5.6.14";
        "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.6.14";
    } }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=PostUrl, com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<7b227374 61747573 223a6661 6c73652c 22657272 6f72223a 22556e6b 6e6f776e 206d6574 686f6422 7d>, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: not found (404)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Very Basic Error in HTTP 404 Means the Page requested is not found.
Are you Uploading something to Server or Fetching Data From server?
If you are fetching Data from server then you have to use.

```
NSString *string = @"Your URL for Request";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {//success response
}failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) { // fail to establish connection with error
}];

[operation start];// start you task
```

if you want all in detail then you can find athttp://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial

Comment: Thanks alot bro..but i am using Afhttprequestoperation manager and also i need to serialize?in future i need to add parameters also.

Answer (score 0):

if you want your request Parameter then use..

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *params = @{@"yourkey": yourvalue,
                     @"yourkey": yourvalue};
[manager POST:@"your URL" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```